# Why is my directive getting called twice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I've got a directive called myEnter, which is attached to an input box in html.
Here's the code:

```
app.directive('myEnter', function () {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind("keydown", function (event) {
            if(event.which === 13) {
                $(".window").animate({ scrollTop: $("#scr").height() }, 1000);
                scope.$apply(function (){
                    scope.$eval(attrs.myEnter);
                });
                event.preventDefault();
            }
            if(event.which === 38) {
                    console.log("up key pressed!");
                    $(".window").animate({ scrollTop: $("#scr").height() }, 1000);
                    scope.$apply(function (){
                        var arr = scope.history;
                        console.log(scope.history);
                        console.log(arr);
                    });
                    event.preventDefault();                 
            }
        });
    };
});
```

What's happening is, it is detecting enter keypresses.
Also, as you can see, I'm also letting it detect "UP" keypresses on the input box.

Both the things are working good. However, whenever I'm pressing the UP key, console logs "up key pressed!" for twice. It should have run for just a single time, and it is running twice for every single UP keypress.

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I believe the directives will be loaded automatically when the HTML page is loaded. What are trying to do with the additional trigger on directives?

Comment: @CrazyMac I am building a terminal app here, have integrated many features, and for the time I'm just curious to implement the history thing - as, by pressing UP key, the user will be able to navigate through all the previous commands that he has fired up before..
http://tinypic.com/r/2zzs0id/9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should maybe try to add

```
event.stopImmediatePropagation() ;
```

after

```
 event.preventDefault();
```

Comment: I didn't know about stopImmediatePropagation(), thanks a lot.
Also, could you please tell me what was happening there?

Comment: event.stopImmediatePropagation() ; will prevent any handlers from executing after

Comment: yes, the name suggests that.. but, my question was, why was my handler executing twice?